# How to select a row with a missing entry in historization?

Tags: sql, oracle

from the following data basis i need to select all `IDQ`'s which do not have an entry for the `11.11.2011`.

```
IDQ | DATE
----------------
 1  | 08.11.2011
 1  | 09.11.2011
 1  | 10.11.2011
 1  | 12.11.2011
 1  | 13.11.2011
```

i can't figure out how to express the sql

```
select
   IDQ
from
   TBL_WITH_IDQ T
where not exists ( DATE = '11.11.2011' ) // sql does not the job
```

Database is a Oracle 11g.

maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select idq
from TBL_WITH_IDQ
group by idq
having max(decode("DATE", '11-Nov-2011',1, 0)) = 0 -- double-quoted keyword column name
```

(Single pass solution) - if your original table is TBL_WITH_IDQ

On the other hand, if your original table is TBL_WITH_DATES and you want to include IDQs with *no* entries at all, I'd suggest this variant of Parkyprg's solution:

```
select IDQ
from TBL_WITH_IDQ t
where not exists
(SELECT null 
 FROM TBL_WITH_DATES d
 where d."DATE" = '11-Nov-2011' and t.idq = d.idq)
```

Comment: The 1st sql seems to do the job.. i'm still evaluating. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   IDQ
from
   TBL_WITH_IDQ T
where IDQ NOT IN ( SELECT IDQ FROM TBL_WITH_DATES where DATE = TO_DATE('11.11.2011','dd.mm.YYYY') )
```

TBL_WITH_DATES - is the table you used in your question and TBL_WITH_IDQ is the original table where IDQ's are defined.

Comment: I'd use NOT EXISTS rather than NOT IN.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a table where IDQ is a unique identifier?  Is so, your query can be reformed like this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  primary_idq_table
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TBL_WITH_IDQ WHERE DATE = '11.11.2011')
```

Comment: no `IDQ` is not my primary key. i have a combined primary key with `IDQ`+`DATE`

Comment: You mis-understand.  Do you have a Different table, separate from the one you mentioned in your question, where IDQ is a unique key?  It would seem to make sense that if you have time varying data assigned to an IDQ, you have an IDQ table somewhere too?